# Having a transparent CCScene

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am designing a game with a pause button. When the player pushes it, I am pushing a CCScene using [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[PausePage scene]];
My PausePageScene doesn't fill the entire screen and I would like to see the CCScene below the Pause Page. Is there a way to do that ? Because the rest of the screen is filled with black instead of being transparent
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm suffering the same and find your question. Pity it's never answered since posted so long ago...

However, maybe my simple test helps. If you use `[currentScene addChild:[PauseLayer node]];` or even `[currentScene addChild:[PausePage scene]];` you will see the pause menu correctly overlapped on the original scene. Maybe you have to use this alternative unless cocos2d has an option to redraw all scenes in the stack rather than the top-most one.

Lots other work to do though, like pause the original scene, handle touch event, etc.